# I am trying to write a utility to draw two images on canvas and want to save as one image object

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have two html img objects with different src urls. I'd like to combine these two images (using canvas), and create one merged img object. I want to give user to select a image from his location and second image will be logo and user can change the location of logo and when click on post button one image object is generated and able to save in database. I am getting one error while writting this javascript object type mismatch I do not under where is the issue...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="drawImage" id="drawImage">
    <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" value="hello" />
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <input type="button" id="mybtn" name="mybtn" value="hello" />
    </form>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var canvas,ctx,img1,img2;
        var imagesLoaded = 0;
        function main() {
            imagesLoaded += 1;
            var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            if(imagesLoaded == 2) {
                // composite now
                console.log(img1);
                ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
                //ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
                ctx.drawImage(img2, 0,100);
            }
        }
        function loadImage(src, onload) {
            // http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = onload;
            img.src = src;
            return img;
        }
        function drawImages(){
            var img1 = loadImage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png', main);
            var img2 = loadImage('http://blog.carazoo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/skoda_logo-300x300.jpg', main);
        }

        $("#mybtn").click(function(){
            //var getImageInput=$("#filename").val();
            //var img1 = loadImage(getImageInput, main);
            //var img2 = loadImage('play-button.png', main);
            drawImages();   
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `img1` and `img2` are locally redeclared inside `drawImages()` and thus the `img1` and `img2` variables inside the `main()` scope point to the undefined `img1` and `img2` in your global scope. The same goes for `canvas` and `ctx`, although this doesn't cause any issues since they're only used inside `main()`.

In short, you can "fix" this by removing the `var` inside `drawImages()`:

```
    function drawImages(){
        img1 = loadImage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png', main);
        img2 = loadImage('http://blog.carazoo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/skoda_logo-300x300.jpg', main);
    }
```

Additionally, you could remove the `canvas` and `ctx` from the global scope, since they're only used inside `main()`.

```
    var img1, img2;
    var imagesLoaded = 0;

    function main() {
        imagesLoaded += 1;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // ...
    }
```

However, you might want to do a more thorough rewrite of your code and properly scope your variables. You want to load the two images first and then render them on the canvas. Those are two distinct problems and it's better to separate the code dealing with them.